# CDO.Message works in VBS but not ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, cdo.message

While the VBS code works fine, I get this error when I run the ASP code:

> "The transport failed to connect to the server. (-2147220973)"

I've tried changing the SMTP Server Port to 25 and 587 without success.

I've Googled for a solution but have not found one yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

ASP code below:

```
<% @Language="VBScript" %>
<%  Option Explicit
    On Error Resume Next
   '*
   '*  Declare Constants
   '*
    Const cASP = "gmail.asp"
    Const cCFG = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
    Const cEMA = "{user}@gmail.com"
    Const cPWD = "{password}"
    Const cSMT = "smtp.gmail.com"
   '*
   '*  Send Email
   '*
    Dim oCDO
    Dim oCFG
    Set oCDO = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set oCFG = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
        oCFG.Fields.Item(cCFG & "sendusing") = 2
        oCFG.Fields.Item(cCFG & "sendusername") = cEMA
        oCFG.Fields.Item(cCFG & "sendpassword") = cPWD
        oCFG.Fields.Item(cCFG & "smtpserver") = cSMT
        oCFG.Fields.Item(cCFG & "smtpserverport") = 465
        oCFG.Fields.Item(cCFG & "smtpauthenticate") = 1
        oCFG.Fields.Item(cCFG & "smtpusessl") = True
        oCFG.Fields.Item(cCFG & "smtpconnectiontimeout") = 10
        oCFG.Fields.Update
        oCDO.Configuration = oCFG 
        oCDO.From = cEMA
        oCDO.To = cEMA
        oCDO.Subject = cSMT & " via " & cASP
        oCDO.HTMLBody = "<h1>" & Now & "</h1>"
        oCDO.Send
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Response.Write "<li>" & Err.Description & " (" & Err.Number & ")"
    Else
        Response.Write "<li>Email Sent!"
    End If
    Set oCFG = Nothing
    Set oCDO = Nothing
%>
```

VBS code below:

```
    Option Explicit
   '*
   '*  Declare Constants
   '*
    Const cVBS = "gmail.vbs"
    Const cCFG = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
    Const cEMA = "{user}@gmail.com"
    Const cPWD = "{password}"
    Const cSMT = "smtp.gmail.com"
   '*
   '*  Send Email
   '*
    Dim oCDO
    Dim oCFG
    Set oCDO = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set oCFG = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
        oCFG.Fields.Item(cCFG & "sendusing") = 2
        oCFG.Fields.Item(cCFG & "sendusername") = cEMA
        oCFG.Fields.Item(cCFG & "sendpassword") = cPWD
        oCFG.Fields.Item(cCFG & "smtpserver") = cSMT
        oCFG.Fields.Item(cCFG & "smtpserverport") = 465
        oCFG.Fields.Item(cCFG & "smtpauthenticate") = 1
        oCFG.Fields.Item(cCFG & "smtpusessl") = True
        oCFG.Fields.Update
        oCDO.Configuration = oCFG
        oCDO.From = cEMA
        oCDO.To = cEMA
        oCDO.Subject = cSMT & " via " & cVBS
        oCDO.HTMLBody = "<h1>" & Now & "</h1>"
        oCDO.Send
    Set oCDO = Nothing
    Set oCFG = Nothing
```

Comment: Have you configured the desired Gmail account to run less secure apps? More on that: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Also, the ASP is likely executed on a different machine and under a different account than the VBS, so firewall and/or webserver settings may be an issue.

Comment: Yes, I had to configure the Gmail account to run less secure apps.

Comment: Of course the ASP is executed on a different machine: shared Web hosting versus my PC.  I don't know what to check/change on the firewall and/or webserver settings...

Comment: The ASP version does work on an A2 hosted account but not on GoDaddy.

Comment: I've tried changing the value of "smtpserver" (i.e. cSMT) from "smtp.gmail.com" to "relay-hosting.secureserver.net" and "localhost" and got the same error.

Comment: I got it to work with help from this article: http://code-excerpts.blogspot.com/2012/02/send-e-mail-using-cdo-on-godaddys.html

Comment: I have run into the same issue some time (years) ago trying to send e-mails through CDO (shared hosting as well). Haven't been able to solve it but fortunately, my webhost offered (and still does) alternative, non-Microsoft, e-mail solutions. You may want to look into that... For my part, I'm using Persits ASPemail to my total satisfaction (I currently don't use the Gmail smtp servers but did yesterday out of curiosity and it works perfectly).

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
.Item(sch & "sendusing") = 2
.Item(sch & "smtpconnectiontimeout") = 900
.Item (sch & "smtpusessl") = true
.Item(sch & "smtpserver") = s_remote_host
.Item(sch & "smtpserverport") = 587 'or 465
.Item(sch & "smtpauthenticate") = 1 'if error still, double-check this
.Item(sch & "sendusername") = SMAUTHUSER
.Item(sch & "sendpassword") = SMAUTHPASS
```

Comment: My previous comment said "I got it to work with help from this article" (without authentication).